# Decrypt File in Java Encrypted via openssl generated (S/Mime) key pair

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt files that were encrypted using an openssl generated public key. I have the key pair that was generated in openssl and can decrypt files with the private key within openssl. However, I am now tasked with decrypting the files in a Java application, using the same private key that was generated via openssl. I have gotten as far as reading the private key into an java.security.PrivateKey object successfully, using Bouncy Castle libraries. I have written (with the help of code I found in various stack overflow posts) three decryption methods, but get various exceptions with each one. I will provide the openssl commands below and also the Java code I used to read in the private key and one of the decrytion methods I've tried.

Generate key pair with openssl:
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out my-private-key.pem 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 730 -key my-private-key.pem -out my-public-key.pem

encrypt file
openssl smime -binary -encrypt -in test.file -out test.file.enc my-public-key.pem

decrypt file
openssl smime -binary -decrypt -inkey ecn-private-key.pem -in test.file.enc -out test.file.dec
(Enter pass phrase for my-private-key.pem)

public key header
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

private key header
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,4EFFB692F0BEBF75B183DB1371979B97

```
        // read private key - this is successful

        private static PrivateKey readPrivateKeyPEM(File file, String password) throws IOException, 
            GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException, PKCSException {
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
               PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(reader);
               Object object = parser.readObject();
               if (object == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No key found in " + file);
               }
               BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
               JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(provider);
                                                
               PEMDecryptorProvider decryptionProvider = new 
               JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().setProvider(provider).build(password.toCharArray());
               PEMKeyPair keypair = ((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(decryptionProvider);
               return converter.getPrivateKey(keypair.getPrivateKeyInfo());         
          }
        }

        // The following method attempts to decrypt file with private key read in above 
           fails
   
        // this fails
        public static void decrypt(PrivateKey privateKey, File encrypted, File decryptedDestination) 
            throws IOException, CMSException {
        
            byte[] encryptedData = Files.readAllBytes(encrypted.toPath());
            CMSEnvelopedDataParser parser = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(encryptedData);        
            RecipientInformation recInfo = getSingleRecipient(parser);
            Recipient recipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey);

            try (InputStream decryptedStream = recInfo.getContentStream(recipient).getContentStream()) {
                Files.copy(decryptedStream, decryptedDestination.toPath());
        }

        
    }
```

The stack trace is:

Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: Unexpected object reading content.
at org.bouncycastle.pkix@1.68/org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSContentInfoParser.(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.pkix@1.68/org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataParser.(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.pkix@1.68/org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataParser.(Unknown Source)
at com.att.floodportal.openssl.EncryptAndDecrypt.decrypt(EncryptAndDecrypt.java:32)
at com.att.floodportal.openssl.JavaSecurityPemUtils.main(JavaSecurityPemUtils.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLApplicationSpecific cannot be cast to class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1SequenceParser (org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLApplicationSpecific and org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1SequenceParser are in module org.bouncycastle.provider@1.68 of loader 'app')

Thank You

Comment: Specify `-outform der` on the `openssl smime -encrypt` and `-inform der` on the `-decrypt`; these are not default. Or for `smime` use `org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMEEnvelopedParser` in bcmail and treat the result as CMSEnveloped. PS: a certificate _contains_ a publickey, but is not the same thing as that publickey.